# Grouping events by day for a ticking machine and counting the first events in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataset from some ticking machines:

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
                      'date':['2019-01-01 07:59:54','2019-01-01 08:00:07','2019-01-01 08:00:07',
                              '2019-01-02 08:00:14','2019-01-02 08:00:16','2019-01-02 08:00:24',
                              '2019-01-03 08:02:38','2019-01-03 08:50:14'],
                      'machine':['A','A','B','C','B','C','D','D']})
my_df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(my_df['date'],infer_datetime_format=True)
my_df
    id  date                machine
0   1   2019-01-01 07:59:54 A
1   2   2019-01-01 08:00:07 A
2   3   2019-01-01 08:00:07 B
3   4   2019-01-02 08:00:14 C
4   5   2019-01-02 08:00:16 B
5   6   2019-01-02 08:00:24 C
6   7   2019-01-03 08:02:38 D
7   8   2019-01-03 08:50:14 D
```

These machines make a tick on a certain moment. So I want to flag when the first tick per machine per day is made. So the expected result is (first the previous table and then the expected table:

```
    id  date                machine   flag
0   1   2019-01-01 07:59:54 A         1
1   2   2019-01-01 08:00:07 A         0
2   3   2019-01-01 08:00:07 B         1
3   4   2019-01-02 08:00:14 C         1
4   5   2019-01-02 08:00:16 B         1
5   6   2019-01-02 08:00:24 C         0
6   7   2019-01-03 08:02:38 D         1
7   8   2019-01-03 08:50:14 D         0

expected:
date        count_flag
2019-01-01  2
2019-01-02  2
2019-01-03  1
```

Since those date time could be repeated I can't put them as index. I have tried this:

```
df.groupby(df['date'].day))['machine'].count()
```

But I must be doing something wrong because it returns `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, the immediate problem is you have too many closed parens in there.  `))` should be `)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `groupby` date (use `.dt.date` to access date of datetime), then count distinct machines with `nunique`:

```
my_df.groupby(my_df.date.dt.date).machine.nunique()

date
2019-01-01    2
2019-01-02    2
2019-01-03    1
Name: machine, dtype: int64
```